# How does await in swift work with tuples?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm trying to make sure I understand the behavior of `await`. Suppose we have the following functions:

```
func do() async {
  //code
}
func stuff() async {
  //code
}
```

The following statements will run `do` and `stuff` sequentially:

```
await do()
await stuff()
```

But the following statement will run `do` and `stuff` in parallel correct?

```
await (do(), stuff())
```

I'm not sure how to check in Xcode if my code runs in parallel or in sequence.

Comment: A quick way would be to write a unit test and set different timeouts on the tuple.  Make the first have a timeout of 1 second and the second have no timeout, where the second one prints "second" and the first one prints "first"

Comment: My gut say's their parallel but I'm curious.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:**

If you want concurrent execution, either use `async let` pattern or a task group.

---

**Long answer:**

You said:

> But the following statement will run do and stuff in parallel correct?
>
> ```swift
> await (do(), stuff())
> ```

No, they will not.

This is best illustrated empirically by:

- Make the task take enough time that concurrency behavior can easily be manifested; and
- Use “Points of Interest” instrument (e.g., by picking the “Time Profiler” template) in Instruments to graphically represent intervals graphically over time.

Consider this code, using the tuple approach:

```swift
import os.log

private let log = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: .pointsOfInterest)
```

And:

```swift
func example() async {
    let values = await (self.doSomething(), self.doSomethingElse())
    print(values)
}

func doSomething() async -> Int {
    spin(#function)
    return 1
}

func doSomethingElse() async -> Int {
    spin(#function)
    return 42
}

func spin(_ name: StaticString) {
    let id = OSSignpostID(log: log)
    os_signpost(.begin, log: log, name: name, signpostID: id, "begin")

    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    while CACurrentMediaTime() - start < 1 { }   // spin for one second

    os_signpost(.end, log: log, name: name, signpostID: id, "end")
}
```

That results in a graph that shows that it is not happening concurrently:

[image]

Whereas:

```swift
func example() async {
    async let foo = self.doSomething()
    async let bar = self.doSomethingElse()
    let values = await (foo, bar)
    print(values)
}
```

That does result in concurrent execution:

[image]

---

Now, in the above examples, I changed the functions so that they returned values (as that is really the only context where using tuples makes any practical sense).

But if they did not return values and you wanted them to run in parallel, you might use a task group:

```swift
func experiment() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask { await self.doSomething() }
        group.addTask { await self.doSomethingElse() }
    }
}

func doSomething() async {
    spin(#function)
}

func doSomethingElse() async {
    spin(#function)
}
```

That results in the same graph where they run in parallel.

You can also just create `Task` instances and then `await` them:

```swift
func experiment() async {
    async let task1 = Task { await doSomething() }
    async let task2 = Task { await doSomethingElse() }
    _ = await task1
    _ = await task2
}
```

But task groups offer greater flexibility when the number of tasks being created may not be known at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not executed in parallel.

Firstly,

```swift
await (do(), stuff())
```

is shorthand syntax for

```swift
(await do(), await stuff())
```

which is evaluated from left to right, just like any other lines of code.

Now, any `await` call suspends the execution of the caller, if the callee suspends. This means the execution will continue with `await stuff()` only after `await do()` finishes.

`await` is a suspension point (actually a *possible* suspension point), this means the execution won't continue until that `await` complete (in either an async or a sync manner, it doesn't matter).

---

> I'm not sure how to check in Xcode if my code runs in parallel or in sequence

You don't need to, unless you don't trust the compiler. The only ways to spawn multiple `await` from the same `async` context (task) is via `async-let` and `TaskGroup`.

But if you really want to check, for learning purposes, others have provided some interesting approaches. I'm just gonna leave mine, which is similar to another already provided one:

```swift
func delay(for interval: TimeInterval = 2.0, marker: StaticString = #function) async {
    print("\(marker) begin")
    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(interval * 1_000_000))
    print("\(marker) end")
}

func `do`() async {
    await delay()
}

func stuff() async {
    await delay()
}

Task {
    let result = await (`do`(), stuff())
}
```

The above code results in the following output:

```
do() begin
do() end
stuff() begin
stuff() end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in order to get concurrent execution you must have an explicit `async let` for each function:

```
actor A {
    var t = 1
    func tt() -> Int {
        for i in 0 ... 1000000 {
            t += i
        }
        let s = t
        t = 1
        return s
    }
}
var a = A()
var b = A()
func go() {
    Task {
        var d = Date()
        await (a.tt(), b.tt())
        print("time=1",d.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        
        
        d = Date()
        await a.tt()
        await b.tt()
        print("time2=",d.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        
        d = Date()
        async let q = (a.tt(), b.tt())
        await q
        print("time3=",d.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        
        d = Date()
        async let q1 = a.tt()
        async let q2 = b.tt()
        await q1
        await q2
        print("time4=",d.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        
        d = Date()
        async let q3 = a.tt()
        async let q4 = b.tt()
        await (q3, q4)
        print("time5=",d.timeIntervalSinceNow)
    }
}
```

printout:

```
time1= -0.4335060119628906
time2= -0.435217022895813
time3= -0.4430699348449707
time4= -0.23430800437927246
time5= -0.23900198936462402
```

Answer (score 0):

Based gloo's answer, another test using sleep as the time-consuming job.

Environment

```
$ xcrun swift -version
swift-driver version: 1.62.15 Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx13.0

$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 14.2
Build version 14C18
```

```
// Executed in playground
import Foundation

actor A {
    func job(_ i: Int, _ d: Date) async throws -> Int {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(2) * NSEC_PER_SEC) // the number 2 can be changed
        print("i=\(i)  time spent = \(-d.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
        return i
    }
}

var a = A()
var b = A()
var d = Date()

func go() {
    Task {
        do {
            // case 1 - non concurrent
            print("case 1")
            d = Date()
            try await (a.job(11, d), b.job(12, d))
            print("time spent case 1 = \(-d.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
            
            // case 2 - non concurrent
            print("case 2")
            d = Date()
            try await a.job(21, d)
            try await b.job(22, d)
            print("time spent case 2 = \(-d.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
            
            // case 3 - non concurrent
            print("case 3")
            d = Date()
            async let q3 = (a.job(31, d), b.job(32, d))
            try await q3
            print("time spent case 3 = \(-d.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
            
            // case 4 - concurrent, 41 or 42 may be printed first
            print("case 4")
            d = Date()
            async let q41 = a.job(41, d)
            async let q42 = b.job(42, d)
            try await q41
            try await q42
            print("time spent case 4 = \(-d.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
            
            // case 4.1 - concurrent, 411 or 412 may be printed first
            print("case 4.1")
            d = Date()
            async let q411 = a.job(411, d)
            async let q412 = b.job(412, d)
            try await q411
            print("case 4.1 mid") //
            try await q412
            print("time spent case 4.1 = \(-d.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
            
            // case 5 - concurrent, 51 or 52 may be printed first
            print("case 5")
            d = Date()
            async let q51 = a.job(51, d)
            async let q52 = b.job(52, d)
            try await (q51, q52)
            print("time spent case 5 = \(-d.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
            
            // case 6 - non concurrent
            print("case 6")
            d = Date()
            _ = (try await a.job(61, d), try await b.job(62, d))
            print("time spent case 6 = \(-d.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
        } catch {
            print("error=\(error)")
        }
    }
}
go()
```

A typical output:

```
case 1
i=11  time spent = 2.1285619735717773
i=12  time spent = 4.261919021606445
time spent case 1 = 4.262814998626709
case 2
i=21  time spent = 2.1167279481887817
i=22  time spent = 4.234173059463501
time spent case 2 = 4.234648942947388
case 3
i=31  time spent = 2.1281230449676514
i=32  time spent = 4.263576984405518
time spent case 3 = 4.264067053794861
case 4
i=42  time spent = 2.130499005317688
i=41  time spent = 2.130929946899414
time spent case 4 = 2.131192922592163
case 4.1
i=412  time spent = 2.133057951927185
i=411  time spent = 2.13319993019104
case 4.1 mid
time spent case 4.1 = 2.133283019065857
case 5
i=51  time spent = 2.132704973220825
i=52  time spent = 2.133439064025879
time spent case 5 = 2.1337080001831055
case 6
i=61  time spent = 2.13224995136261
i=62  time spent = 4.265568017959595
time spent case 6 = 4.266121029853821
```